# Use Qt Help .qhc files into QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I would like to display .qhc files into my QML/QtQuick application, does anyone tried to do that?

I know that I can use QHelpEngine on the C++ part, but I would like to use qhc files directly on QML.